# Colored lines inside the rectangles of respective colors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to draw below figure. But I am not able to put the lines inside the rectangular boxes, of respective colors as written inside the boxes. I also would like to have text, maybe color name here, but without any lines crossing the text(as I try to show it in case of RED and YELLOW).[image]
My MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,3);
    \shade[top color=yellow, bottom color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,-1);
    \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!40!black] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
    \draw (2,0) rectangle (5,1);
    \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy with the `patterns` library (section 60 of the pgfmanual).

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[top color=yellow, bottom color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,-1);
    \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!40!black] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,3);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
    \draw[pattern=vertical lines] (2,0) rectangle (5,1);
    \draw[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=yellow] (2,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: With annotations. You only need to modify the `mynode` style to change the behavior. I also made the boundaries have the same color as the lines.

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\tikzset{mynode/.style args={#1 | #2}{midway,%
node contents={\contour{white}{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}},%
font=\small,inner sep=0pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[top color=yellow, bottom color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,-1);
    \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!40!black] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red,draw=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,3)
    node[mynode=red | hello];
    \draw[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue,draw=blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,1)
    node[mynode=blue | ducks];
    \draw[pattern=vertical lines] (2,0) rectangle (5,1) 
    node[mynode=black | hello];
    \draw[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=yellow,draw=yellow] (2,0) rectangle (3,3)
    node[mynode=yellow | world];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great one! I also would like to have text, maybe color name here, but without any lines crossing the text. Can it be done?

Comment: @Shamina Sure. Text color black or the same color as the lines?

Comment: Same as the color of the lines. thks

Comment: @Shamina Done. If you change your mind, you only need to adjust the `mynode` style.

Comment: If I am trying to replace `mynode=red` to say `mynode=hello`. Then it's becoming black, some errors. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: I added another version which takes two arguments.

Comment: May be the last disturbance. Is it possible to have the boundaries of the rectangle same as of the color of the lines, instead all are black? Sorry

Comment: @Shamina That's easy, just add `draw=red`, say. I updated my answer accordingly.