# Drawing Annulus region with rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I realize that I have to plot different figure then [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442020/colored-lines-inside-the-rectangles-of-respective-colors). Interestingly, @marmot has already provided a wonderful and [very beautiful solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442020/colored-lines-inside-the-rectangles-of-respective-colors/442021#442021). I will use their code for MWE alogwith mine(small part). But I couldn't achieve the new figure as well.
[image]
My MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\tikzset{mynode/.style args={#1 | #2}{midway,%
        node contents={\contour{white}{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}},%
        font=\small,inner sep=0pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue,draw=blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,1)
    node[mynode=blue | blue];
    \draw[pattern=vertical lines] (2,0) rectangle (5,1) 
    node[mynode=black | black];
    \draw[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=yellow,draw=yellow] 
    (0:2cm) -- (0:3cm)
    arc (0:105:3cm) -- (105:2cm) node[mynode=yellow | yello]
    arc (105:0:2cm) -- cycle;
    \draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red,draw=red] (-1,0) -- (0,0)
    arc (180:120:2cm) -- (120:1cm) node[mynode=red | red]
    arc (120:180:1cm) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to slightly adjust the style made by @marmot [in the question you referenced to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442021/74459), so that you can place the nodes wherever you want. I only removed the `midway` option.

Using the `++(<x>,<y>)` notation you can specify a coordinate relative to the last coordinate Tikz processed. This also works with the `++(<angle>:<radius>)` polar coordinates.

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\tikzset{mynode/.style args={#1 | #2}{%midway,%
        node contents={\contour{white}{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}},%
        font=\small,inner sep=0pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] 
        (-1,0) rectangle (3,1) node[mynode=blue | Blue,midway];
    \draw[pattern=vertical lines] 
        (2,0) rectangle (5,1) node[mynode=black | Black,midway];
    \draw[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=yellow] 
        (2,0) -- ++(0,1) arc (0:105:1cm) -- ++(105:1cm) arc (105:0:2cm) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
    \node at (2,2) [mynode=yellow | Hello];
    \draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] 
        (0,0) -- ++(0,1) arc (180:75:1cm) -- ++(75:1cm) arc (75:180:2cm) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
    \node at (0,2) [mynode=red | Red];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, midway was specific to the previous question, didn't expect to be migrated. ;-) +1 of course ;-)

Comment: @Max Is there a way to write Red and Yellow in curve manner(just for anesthetic)? Many thanks!

Comment: @Shamina well, I believe it is possible, but it seems to interfere with the `contour` package. You should ask a separate question and let the TeX magicians work on it :)

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness: without redefining the `mynode` style and yellow on the left and red on the right as in the OP's sketch. The contours are adapted from [Max Snippe's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442048/121799) (or, more precisely, stolen ;-), and of course with a cheat (which, however, spares you from putting the coordinates of the nodes in the rectangles by hand ;-).

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\tikzset{mynode/.style args={#1 | #2}{midway,%
        node contents={\contour{white}{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}},%
        font=\small,inner sep=0pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue,draw=blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,1)
    node[mynode=blue | blue];
    \draw[pattern=vertical lines] (2,0) rectangle (5,1) 
    node[mynode=black | black];
    \draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] 
        (2,0) -- ++(0,1) arc (0:105:1cm) -- ++(105:1cm) arc (105:0:2cm) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
    \draw[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=yellow] 
        (0,0) -- ++(0,1) arc (180:75:1cm) -- ++(75:1cm) arc (75:180:2cm) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
    \path (0,2) -- (0,2) node[mynode=yellow | yello] 
    (2,2) --(2,2) node[mynode=red | Red];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

@Shamina: this is really just for fun, please accept Max Snippe's answer.

**ADDENDUM**: There seem to be some issues with the contour, at least in the conversion to png. One way to fix it is to increase the contour number.

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\contournumber{64}
\tikzset{mynode/.style args={#1 | #2}{midway,%
        node contents={\contour{white}{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}},%
        font=\small,inner sep=0pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue,draw=blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,1)
    node[mynode=blue | blue];
    \draw[pattern=vertical lines] (2,0) rectangle (5,1) 
    node[mynode=black | black];
    \draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] 
        (2,0) -- ++(0,1) arc (0:105:1cm) -- ++(105:1cm) arc (105:0:2cm) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
    \draw[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=yellow] 
        (0,0) -- ++(0,1) arc (180:75:1cm) -- ++(75:1cm) arc (75:180:2cm) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
    \path (0,2) -- (0,2) node[mynode=yellow | yellow] 
    (2,2) --(2,2) node[mynode=red | Red];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does the `contour` not work on the `yello` node? (+1 of course for cheating).

Comment: @MaxSnippe Actually, on my pdf there is a contour. But I agree, for some reason this does not look like that on the converted png. One way to go is to set `\contournumber{64}` to make really really sure that in the conversion nothing goes wrong.